# Ternary Classification of the type 'A', 'B' or 'any'?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, text-classification

For any **general** machine learning model (though I am currently working with neural networks), for the task of

> classifying the elements of a set into three groups ('A' or 'B' or 'any'),

(here, labeling as '*A*' means that the **only** valid label is 'A' (similarly '*B*'), and '*any*' means that **both** the tags 'A' and 'B' are equally valid), ***what kind of loss function should be used***?

This can be solved using the techniques related to the more general problem of "ternary classification," but I think I'll lose some information by this generalization.

*For the sake of example, let's say we want to classify verbs (English language) according to their tense forms (let us only consider the present and past tense)*

Then the model should classify

> {"work", "eat", "sing", ...} as "*present tense*"

> {"worked", "ate", "sang", ...} as "*past tense*"

and,

> {"read", "put", "cut", ...} as "*any*"

(note that the pronunciation is different for the present and past tense of 'read', but we are considering text-based classification)

This is different from the task that I am working on but probably should work as a valid example for this particular question.

PS: I am a student, and only have a basic understanding of this field, so if needed, please ask for any clarification regarding the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are in the situation of multi-label classification and not multi-class classifcation.

As stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification):

> In machine learning, multi-label classification and the strongly
> related problem of multi-output classification are variants of the
> classification problem where multiple labels may be assigned to each
> instance

Which means that instances can have more than 1 class associated to them.

Usually, when you work with a binary classification (e.g. 0, 1 classes) you can have as final layer of your network one neuron, which will output continues values between 0 and 1, using as activation function the sigmoid one, and as loss the `binary cross-entropy`

Given your situation you could decide to use:

- two neurons as output of your neural network
- for each one you can use the `sigmoid` activation function
- and as loss the `binary-cross entropy`

in this way, each instance can be associated with both classes with a specific probability by the model.

This means that for each instance, you should associate two classes, or rather *"labels"*.
For example, for your verbs you should have "past", "present" classes:

```
         present  past
work:    1      0
worked:  0      1
read     1      1
```

And your model will try to output two probabilities, with the architecture explained before:

```
         present  past   sum
work:    0.9      0.3    1.2
worked:  0.21     0.8    1.01
read     0.86     0.7    1.5
```

Basically, you have two independent probabilites (if you check, the sum of one row is not 1), and therefore you can associate to one instance both classes.

Instead, if you wanted a mutually exclusive classification, with more than 2 classes, you should have used the `categorical crossentropy` as loss, and the `softmax activation function` in your last layer, the which will basically handle the outputs to generate a vector of probabilities that sums to 1. Example

```
         present   past     both   sum
work:    0.7       0.2      0.1    1
worked:  0.21      0.7      0.19   1
read     0.33      0.33     0.33   1
```

Check [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-label-image-classification-with-neural-network-keras-ddc1ab1afede) to see an extensive example